# OrgChartjs : How to make all children directly connected to parent

Tags: javascript, orgchart

Is it possible if I can directly connect all children to 1 parent in Balkan OrgChart.js?
This is what I have as a starting point from the documentation of OrgChart.js.

```
window.onload = function () {
    OrgChart.templates.family_template = Object.assign({}, OrgChart.templates.ana);
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.size = [86, 86];
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.plus = "";
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.minus = "";
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.rippleRadius = 40;
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.name = '<text style="font-size: 12px;" fill="#000000" x="43" y="100" text-anchor="middle">{val}</text>';
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.title = '<text style="font-size: 12px;" fill="#aeaeae" x="43" y="115" text-anchor="middle">{val}</text>';
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.img = '<clipPath id="{randId}"><circle cx="43" cy="43" r="38.5"></circle></clipPath></circle><image preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" clip-path="url(#{randId})" xlink:href="{val}" x="3" y="3"  width="80" height="80"></image>';
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.node = '<circle stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke="#aeaeae" cx="43" cy="43" r="41.5"></circle>';
    OrgChart.templates.family_template.defs = '<g transform="matrix(0.05,0,0,0.05,-13,-15.5)" id="baby"><circle cx="260" cy="310" r="200" fill="#ffffff"></circle><path fill="#aeaeae" d="m468.64 268.32h-13.591c-18.432-89.348-95.612-157.432-189.139-161.798-.501-.185-1.015-.348-1.545-.482-18.363-4.622-31.188-22.595-31.188-43.707 0-17.828 14.468-32.333 32.252-32.333 12.573 0 22.802 10.258 22.802 22.866 0 8.284 6.716 15 15 15s15-6.716 15-15c0-29.15-23.687-52.866-52.802-52.866-34.326 0-62.252 27.962-62.252 62.333 0 17.876 5.828 34.443 15.769 47.432-80.698 15.127-144.725 78.25-161.291 158.555h-13.591c-24.103 0-43.712 19.596-43.712 43.683 0 24.086 19.609 43.682 43.712 43.682h14.692c20.935 89.871 101.582 157.018 197.596 157.018s176.66-67.148 197.596-157.018h14.692c24.103 0 43.712-19.596 43.712-43.682 0-24.087-19.609-43.683-43.712-43.683zm-265.054 55.257c-8.284-.024-14.981-6.758-14.958-15.043.007-2.337-.708-13.999-15.481-14.041-.026 0-.053 0-.08 0-14.697 0-15.475 11.62-15.481 13.953-.023 8.284-6.75 15.007-15.043 14.957-8.284-.024-14.98-6.759-14.957-15.043.038-13.322 5.349-25.101 14.955-33.166 8.223-6.904 19.065-10.702 30.543-10.702h.148c11.534.033 22.412 3.896 30.63 10.876 9.559 8.12 14.803 19.928 14.765 33.25-.023 8.27-6.735 14.957-14.999 14.957-.013.002-.027.002-.042.002zm52.766 129.374c-26.485 0-48.033-21.533-48.033-48.002 0-8.284 6.716-15 15-15s15 6.716 15 15c0 9.926 8.089 18.002 18.033 18.002s18.033-8.076 18.033-18.002c0-8.284 6.716-15 15-15s15 6.716 15 15c-.001 26.469-21.548 48.002-48.033 48.002zm113.765-129.374c-.015 0-.029 0-.044 0-8.284-.024-14.98-6.759-14.957-15.043.016-5.445-1.993-9.263-6.14-11.673-5.407-3.142-13.27-3.165-18.695-.053-4.161 2.387-6.191 6.193-6.207 11.638-.023 8.27-6.735 14.957-14.999 14.957-.015 0-.029 0-.043 0-8.284-.024-14.981-6.758-14.958-15.043.046-16.149 7.802-29.845 21.281-37.576 14.814-8.497 33.929-8.443 48.695.138 13.434 7.807 21.112 21.547 21.066 37.696-.023 8.271-6.735 14.959-14.999 14.959z"/> </g>';
    OrgChart.templates.family_template_blue = Object.assign({}, OrgChart.templates.family_template);
    OrgChart.templates.family_template_blue.node = '<circle stroke-width="3" fill="none" stroke="#039BE5" cx="43" cy="43" r="41.5"></circle>';

var chart = new OrgChart(document.getElementById("tree"), {
    template: "family_template",
    enableSearch: false,
    siblingSeparation: 100,
    nodeBinding: {
        field_0: 'id',
        name: "name",
        title: "title",
        img: "img",
    },
    tags: {
        blue: {
            template: "family_template_blue"
        }
    }
});

chart.on('render-link', function(sender, args){
    if (args.cnode.ppid != undefined){
        args.html += '<use xlink:href="#baby" x="'+ args.p.xa +'" y="'+ args.p.ya +'"/>';
    }
});

chart.load([          
        { id: 1, tags: ["blue"], name: "King George VI", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f1.png"},
        { id: 2, pid: 1, tags: ["left-partner"], name: "Queen Elizabeth", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png" },
        { id: 3, pid: 1, tags: ["partner"], name: "Queen Elizabeth", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png" },
        { id: 4, pid: 1, name: "Queen Elizabeth", title: "The Queen Mother", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png" },
        { id: 5, pid: 1, tags: ["right-partner"], name: "Queen Elizabeth", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png" },
        { id: 6, pid: 1, tags: ["partner"], name: "Queen Elizabeth", img: "https://cdn.balkan.app/shared/f2.png" },
    ]);
};
```

And this is the result for that one.
[image]

Is there a possibilty to have a result like this?
[image]

I'm stuck on this point and I don't know where to proceed next.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this with Org Chart JS.
It will be possible to do it with some of the future products of Balkan APP.
For now you can choose one of the libraries here:
https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/best-free-javascript-graph-visualization-libraries--cms-41710